# Resize ScrollView when keyboard visible (Android ReactNative Expo)

Tags: android, react-native, expo, resize, android-scrollview

I have a simple app structure of a `View` segment, a `ScrollView` segment, and a `View` segment, arranged vertically. The last `View` segment contains a `TextInput`. I've spent so much time on this, but on iOS, the keyboard behaves fine, and the `ScrollView` decreases in height while the input `View` moves up to accomodate the keyboard. On Android, the entire screen pans up, causing the top `View` to disappear out of the screen. Is there any way to mimic the behavior of the iOS keyboard on Android? I want all three Views to be visible, and the keyboard's space should be given up by the `ScrollView` which resizes.

[image: None][image: None]

Simplified code:

```js
        <View>
            <SafeAreaView>
                <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : ''} className={`h-full justify-start flex-col px-5`}>
                    {Platform.OS === 'android' && (
                        <View style={{
                            height: StatusBar.currentHeight
                        }}></View>
                    )}
                    <View className={'flex-row justify-between py-2'}>
                        <TouchableOpacity className={`px-3 py-3 rounded-3xl`}>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity className={`px-3 py-3 rounded-3xl`}>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                    <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} className={`flex-1 mt-2 mb-3 rounded-3xl`} contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}>
                        <View className={`px-5 py-2.5 flex-1 justify-start`}>
                               <OtherStuff />
                        </View>
                    </ScrollView>
                    <View className={`my-2.5 px-5 py-4 rounded-3xl`}>
                        <TextInput className={`rounded-3xl w-full text-xl border px-5 py-3 my-4`} />
                    </View>
                </KeyboardAvoidingView>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </View>
        </KeyboardAvoiderProvider>
```